# Why am I getting errors with my Reachability.h file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, reachability

Why am I getting the following errors from my Reachability.h file in XCode? See the attachment below:

http://file.reddexuk.com/2h2K152b2b2c270I2Z2M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot some depenencies for ASIHTTPRequest.
Please add the following frameworks

- CFNetwork.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework
- MobileCoreServices.framework
- CoreGraphics.framework
- libz.dylib

Even though i would personally move on to AFNetworking, as Ben is no longer supporting ASIHTTPRequest and its a discontinued class.

Shai.

Comment: I have added these frameworks... If I were to go with AFNetworking, how would I save a full webpage (will external resources) and load it again offline? Is this simple to do? Where is there sample code or a tutorial? :-)

Comment: Im pretty sure you didn't add all these frameworks if you are getting these errors. _inflateEnd, _inflate, _deflateEnd, _inflateInit2_ _defalt and _deflateInit2_ are part of libz.dylib . I'm not sure about kReachabilityChangedNotiication, seems you're missing some of the includes. Its hard to know without having the actual project.

Comment: If there isn't anything sensitive in your project i would recommend you'll upload it and i'll try helping you. it could be a million reasons :)

Comment: I've removed ASIHTTPRequest as you said and added AFNetworking but I get this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376094/why-is-afnetworking-bringing-up-an-error-in-xcode